# Cannot get mPdf working

Tags: mpdf

I use `composer require mpdf/mpdf` to install it.

when trying example I got error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting '&' or variable
>   (T_VARIABLE) in /var/www/randomizer/library/mpdf/src/functions-dev.php
>   on line 4

hope someone can help me with this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you are running PHP5.6 or higher when attempting to run the examples. Your CLI might be a different version which is why it didn't complain when you installed Mpdf via composer.

Comment: CLI gave me version 5.6, while phpinfo() before mpdf->output gave me older version.  I had to enable version 5.6.
Thx for pointing me in right direction.